# Adding a footnote seperator

Tags: footnotes

I inserted a footnote using \footnote{text}, now the text is appearing at the bottom of the page, but there is no line separating the main text from the footnote. How to make it show?

Comment: Your class might be redefining the way `\footnoterule` works. Could you provide the community with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the behaviour you experience? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`. We want to copy-and-paste-and-compile it and see exactly the same problem you're experiencing.

Comment: Depends on the documentclass and maybe even packages in use. Please [add more information](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: Delete the contents of your document and use `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}<Choice of text>\footnote{<Choice of footnote content>}\end{document}`. This will definitely solve the problem.

Comment: @cfr your way works! but I am using \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran} , so it is not working

Comment: `*2446* % IEEE does not use footnote rules`

Comment: @AmiraAkra Indeed. That's why an MWE is so important.

Comment: @cfr using Johannes_B's idea mentioned below worked fine, but  eventually I decided against using a footnote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 2446 of `IEEEtran.cls` states

```
% IEEE does not use footnote rules
```

When submitting to the publisher, they will simply revert any non-conforming changes.

For academic purposes, we can place a footnote rule, by copying the definition from `article.cls` or any other class.  It shouldn't be done however.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern-3\p@
  \hrule\@width.4\columnwidth
  \kern2.6\p@}
  \makeatother
\begin{document}Choice of text
\footnote{Choice of footnote content}
\end{document}.
```